# Bootstrap navbar-right not working on fix-top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the nav links aligned right of the nav bar. However my nav links are showing up next to the logo on the left. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light white-bg purple-top-strip">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/presitskillsbank-logo.png" width="102" height="40" alt=""/></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: It works fine for me you are probably making some css mistake. Could you put your code in codepen, jsbin or something similar so we can see what is happening.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 My jsbin is: https://jsbin.com/poxibac

Comment: Have you checked my answer and jsbin I've added ? It that what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some mistakes the way you structured HTML, this would work in bootstrap 3, but in bootstrap 4 it will not.

Here is example of code that would work in bootstrap 4:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is JSBin with example http://jsbin.com/pagigugelo/edit?output

Comment: Thank you so much @Zvezdas1989 - that works like a charm!

Comment: No problem happy to help.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the working code for your quick reference.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39316/

```css
.navbar-toggler {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar-nav li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @Mike, let me know what further issues you are facing here. I believe the fiddle I've shared with you is having right aligned nav